# Как сделать реальный ландшафт?

Tags: unity3d

Допустим на unity мне необходимо получить ландшафт реальной местности, не очень большой (например  3*3 км). Как это можно сделать?

Comment: нужно взять карту высот и использовать ее как  bump map для плоскости.

Comment: Так, хорошо, это я слышал вроде. И откуда мне взять карту высот? То, что я находил, слишком огромная площадь и неудобна для обработки

Comment: вообще есть сервисы в интернете, на которых можно запросить интересующий регион, но я сейчас не подскажу, пишу с телефона

Comment: https://terrain.party

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Воа, вот это сервис, круто!

Comment: вот что получается при помощи данных с этого ресурса и плейна с кастомным шейдером https://imgur.com/hjLGVWF

Comment: Да, очень круто, спасибо большое!!!